# how to allow IAM role to assume another IAM role, via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

adding an IAM role via cloudformation , where I want to add a trust policy such that , another IAM role (arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/otherrole)  from another aws account can assume my role. but I get an error "Has prohibited field resource ( service: AmazonIdentityManagement; status Code: 400 .....

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  SomeRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Resource: arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/otherrole
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AssumeRolePolicyDocument` do not have `Resource`. It should be `Principal`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  SomeRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              AWS: arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/otherrole
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
      ...
```

Comment: thanks. one follow up question . the section under AssumeRolePolicyDocument is the trust policy section of an IAM role?

Comment: @ozil Yes, its a trust policy.